# Name of a special matrix

Tags: matrices, terminology

I have a matrix which is kind of symmetrical with the other diagonal, i.e., something like

$$A = \left[ \begin{array}{c c c c}
   a & b & c & d \\
   e & f & g & c \\
   h & i & f & b \\
   j & h & e & a
 \end{array} \right]$$

Does this matrix have a special name in literature? What are it's properties?

And a matrix that is symmetrical by both diagonals

$$A = \left[ \begin{array}{c c c c}
   a & b & c & d \\
   b & e & f & c \\
   c & f & e & b \\
   d & c & b & a
 \end{array} \right]$$

What's the name of it? Any interesting properties?

Comment: The second is **bisymmetric**. I don't know a name for the more general first.

Comment: The first is a [persymmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persymmetric_matrix) matrix.

Comment: [relevant question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1811421/81360) on persymmetric matrices

Answer (score 5):

(Turning the comments into an answer)

Yes, the first matrix is [persymmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persymmetric_matrix), and the second is [bisymmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisymmetric_matrix).