# Are there mathematically interesting symmetric matrices with the other symmetries of the square?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, invariance

Symmetric matrices are square arrays of integers with a symmetry with respect to the main diagonal. However, there are several other symmetries of the square (symmetry with respect to the other diagonal, rotation by 90°, rotation by 180°, symmetry with respect to a horizontal or vertical axis).

Are some of the matrices invariant under the other symmetries of the square mathematically interesting?

Comment: Are you defining symmetric matrices with entries from $\mathbb{Z}$? Also, could you paraphrase your last question? I don't understand the problem statement.

Comment: @BokaPeer No, the entries could be any field or ring.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe All of these do not obey any symmetry of the square.

Comment: Start with a simple case e.g. $2 \times 2$ matrices.  Symmetric under rotation by $90 ^\circ$ is not very interesting.  Symmetric under rotation by $180 ^\circ$ is slightly more interesting.

Comment: @Phira You might find [this post about "persymmetric matrices"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1811421/81360) interesting.