# Defining a type of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, definition

I was wondering if there is a name for matrix like following:

[image]

It is like a symmetric matrix but to the other side. Is there a definition for this type of matrices?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378696/name-of-a-special-matrix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name of a special matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378696/name-of-a-special-matrix)

Comment: It's a Toeplitz matrix.

Comment: @bounceback This question is not a duplicate of the linked "Name of special matrix" question, because "Name of special matrix" is not about Toeplitz matrices. The matrix given in this question has a structure which is not present in the other question.

Comment: Must the diagonals have the same entries?

Comment: OK, perhaps I was thrown by the line 'It is like a symmetric matrix but to the other side', but I see your point.

Answer (score 3):

As @user1551 mentioned, this is a Toeplitz matrix:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix

Comment: I had taken the second definition of the OP "symmetric with respect to the second diagonal" and didn't pay attention to the example that was in fact more restrictive : all descending diagonals have the same entry...

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : I stick to your definition "It is like a symmetric matrix but to the other side". I don't take into account the supplementary fact that all descending diagonals contain the same entry that exists on your example but may not exist as well.

Up to my knowledge, this kind of matrix has no special name. Let us call them provisionally $T$-matrices.

It must be understood that all operations that can be done on $T$-matrices are literally "mirrored" into operations done on symmetric matrices $S$ through operation ;

$$T \to JTJ=JTJ^{-1}=S\tag{1}$$

with matrix $J$ defined by :

$$J:=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \text{with} \ \  J^2=I \ \iff \ J^{-1}=J$$

(or the equivalent in $n$ dimensions).

Remark : (1) is a bijection, with inverse operation $T=JSJ$. Moreover, this relationship shows that $S$ and $T$ are conjugated ; thus in particular, they have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: That can't be right. For example, the space  of symmetric $4\times 4$ matrices has dimension $10$, while the space of $4\times 4$ T matrices has dimension $7$.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich See the "disclaimer" I just added in front of my answer.

Comment: The term is [persymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persymmetric_matrix). I would say you answered the question as asked. The example is also Toeplitz, but that is too restrictive.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo You are right : I had seen this term, but forgot it.

Comment: Right. You say you used the definition "It is like a symmetric matrix but to the other side". I couldn't/cam't figure out exactly what that means...